# wsimport error : xml type not found

Tags: xml, web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

I am trying to generate client artifacts from the WSDL file as mentioned below using wsimport <>. The WSDL file and the error am getting is mentioned below. The wsimport is not able to resolve the namespace - tns, but it is the same namespace as thetarget namespace of the wsdl. Tried compiling using catalog file and binding file but nothing works. Am not clear why the tns namespace is not resolving when its the same as target name space. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks .

### WSDL File

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.3-07/10/2008 08:41 PM(bt). --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.3-07/10/2008 08:41 PM(bt). -->
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/" name="StatementprofileWebservice">
<message name="getSIRIStatementprofile">
<part name="StatementprofileRequestBean" type="tns:statementprofileRequest" />
</message>
<message name="getSIRIStatementprofileResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:StatementprofileResponse" />
</message>
<portType name="StatementprofileWebservice">
<operation name="getSIRIStatementprofile">
<input message="tns:getSIRIStatementprofile" />
<output message="tns:getSIRIStatementprofileResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="StatementprofileWebservicePortBinding" type="tns:StatementprofileWebservice">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc" />
<operation name="getSIRIStatementprofile">
<soap:operation soapAction="" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/" />
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="StatementprofileWebservice">
<port name="StatementprofileWebservicePort" binding="tns:StatementprofileWebservicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="https://webdev.ams1907.com:443/Statementprofile/StatementprofileWebservice" />
</port>
</service>
</definitions>

D:\bea3\jdk160_05\bin>wsimport StatementProfile.wsdl
parsing WSDL...
```

**Error**

```
[ERROR] XML type "{http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.ups.com/}statementprofileRequest" could not be resolved, XML to JAVA binding failed! Please check the wsdl:part "StatementprofileRequestBean" in the wsdl:message "{http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/}getSIRIStatementprofile".
  line 5 of file:/D:/bea3/jdk160_05/bin/StatementProfile.wsdl
```

**Tried using this binding file**

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer=" system"> 
    < system systemId="http://mahapps.inside.ups.com/AccountProfile/AccountProfileWebservice?wsdl" uri="AccountProfileWebservice.wsdl"/> 
</catalog> 

**Tried using binding file**

<bindings
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://webservice.accountprofile.billing.ups.com/"
    wsdlLocation="http://mahapps.inside.ups.com/AccountProfile/AccountProfileWebservice?wsdl"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
        <package name="com.test">

        </package>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks i added the types as you suggested and it worked like a charm. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your `<types>` element? It should contain the XSD declarations for the types your process is complaining about. Your WSDL should either have an `import` somewhere to import the XSD type declarations:

```
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace="http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/" schemaLocation="your-schema.xsd" />             
    </schema>
</types>
```

or the XSD *embedded* in your `<types>` element:

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/" targetNamespace="http://webservice.statementprofile.billing.aosoft.com/"> 
        <xsd:complexType name="statementprofileRequest">
            ...
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="StatementprofileResponse">
            ...
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

or some other way to feed the `wsimport` app with that XSD (perhaps via bindings), but if you can insert the `<types>` info, you should be able to validate.

Comment: This is the WSDL other client applications have been using for a while. We are consuming it for the first time and i guess the WSDL is just fine as others are currently consuming it. May be as you said i have to use the bindings . Let me check with the WSDL providers

Comment: The type information has to be sent to the processor somehow. Either in the standard forms shown above (import, types) or by some other non-standard means.

Comment: Am clear on import and types, but not clear on what is meant by the non-standard means . Can you please detail

Comment: Thanks for your previous answers.

Comment: I mean that the XML above will not validate independent of `wsimport`, since it doesn't contain a XSD to declare the types it needs. To make it validate it should have a `<types>` element containing a XSD, a `<types>` element with an import (or at least an simple `import` to a XSD - although this might not validate in all processors). If `wsimport` allows invalid schemas, it requires that you somehow provide it with the data that is missing (that's why you get the error). That is non-standard with respect to WSDL or XSD.